# Increasing input font size without affecting padding

Tags: html, css

I have a input text field with a padding of 1rem. I'm trying to increase the font-size to 1rem  without affecting the size of the input field. The field must stay the same height. Any suggestions?

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="search" placeholder="search">
```

My CSS:

```
.search {
   padding: 1rem;
   font-size: 1rem;
```

Comment: You set a height to the input

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to do the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a `height` and `width` properties to fix the size of the input field. That should definitely work. If you need something else, just let me know I can help you anything with CSS.